# Filled data disappear when print the fillable pdf by chrome print button

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat

**When Open pdf in browser**

[image: When open pdf in browser]

**When pdf print in chrome browser **

[image: When pdf print in chrome browser]

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue in other browsers like IE, Firefox?

Comment: @Soubik, Yes in other browser have same issue .

Comment: Please also check in Acrobat Reader and post the PDF generation code which you have if possible

Comment: @Souvik when we have print this pdf with adove reader or adove acrobat DC print option, then it is working fine.

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF with which you observe the issue?

Comment: @mkl yes sure, please check below link for sample of pdf :-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7wovu2wxqr2yu1/Californiaold.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Hhmmm, I've looked into your example file. Indeed, already in the print preview the field contents are dropped but there does not seem anything invalid in the PDF, so I would assume it is a shortcoming of the PDF implementation of the browsers in question.